# How to write monospaced font when using setmainfont{}

Tags: fonts

I am using a local font (.otf file), loading with `setmainfont{My font}`. It works just fine throughout the document. But when I want to use a typewriter text, it will just go back to regular Roman font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

This is Minion Pro.
\texttt{But this is Roman.}

\end{document}
```

The same happens with, e.g., `\usepackage{alltt}` for typing code in monospaced font.
Invoking a local font momentarily in the text does not work either, like there is no way to override `setmainfont`.

Comment: The typewriter font is declared with `\setmonofont{...}`, see section 1 Main commands of the fontspec documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was it. What a fast, simple and effective answer :)